# what's wrong with my urls.py in this example?

Tags: django, django-urls, django-userena

I just installed userena, and had the example working from the tutorial, but as soon as I added in a single line in URLS.py, I'm getting an error.  In the example below, I added the line mapping the home function from views.py

Now the issue I'm having is that when I go to 127.0.0.1/8000, I get TypeError: string is not callable, but then oddly, if I go to accounts/signup or accounts/signin, I am getting the template that should be appearing if i go to 127.0.0.1/8000.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from accounts import views
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r"^$", 'home'),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^accounts/', include('userena.urls')),
)
```

Here is my accounts/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def home(request):

return render('homepage.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the quotes in the url and import that view

```
from accounts.views import home

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r"^$", home),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^accounts/', include('userena.urls')),
)
```

You can steel use the strings in the url() but you must use the format 'app.views.viewname'

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r"^$", 'accounts.views.home'),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^accounts/', include('userena.urls')),
)
```

Or name the module in the first argument as string to patterns()

```
urlpatterns = patterns('accounts.views',
    url(r"^$", 'home'),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^accounts/', include('userena.urls')),
)
```

Comment: now I get attributeError at /    str object has no attribute META

Comment: that is another problem, paste the traceback in your question please.

Comment: No, it's still valid to use dotted names. It is deprecated in 1.8, but possible to still use this form.

Answer (score 0):

the issue was I forgot to include the request in the return render.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is that `render` is being called incorrectly. Actually, the views.py file would raise a SyntaxError, but we'll let that slide :)

```
# views.py
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'homepage.html')
```